# Would you tell me if I have used EMPHATIC ADVERB correctly?

Tags: adverbs

Do you have your driving licence with yourself?

Do you have your driving licence with you?

Would you tell me which one is right?

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence is incorrect. There is no use of a reflexive/emphatic pronoun with this meaning. Your second sentence is right:

> Do you have your driving licence with/ **or on** you?

"With oneself" can be used with an adjective, to form sentences like, "Are you pleased with yourself?" "You look happy with yourself"

Answer (score 1):

Here's two ways to express this:

"Do you have your Driver License with you?"

"Do you have your Driver License on you?"

In the US, a Driver License is a specific thing, we don't have "driving" licenses.  However, people will often say "driver's" license

"with" implies the object is nearby and easily accessible, in the glovebox, in a bag.
"on" implies on your person, such as in a pocket.

Comment: It's funny.  My driver's license says "driver license" on it, but I'd never actually say that out loud.  To me, at least, it sounds pretty strange!